# What happens when a sentence and an aside require different sentence structures?

Tags: syntactic-analysis, coordinating-conjunctions, conjunction-reduction, constituents

How do you handle when an aside -- a parenthetical or a dashed aside -- doesn't fit with what follows, but since the aside is the "closest" thing, the original thing doesn't fit either.

Consider (speaking about web crawlers here):

> You let them -- even encouraged them -- consume your content, and in return they sent you traffic.

Without the aside, we have:

> You let them consume your content...

That works.

But the aside wants a "to"

> You encouraged them TO consume your content...

I would think that you should cater to the main sentence, without the aside (so, no "to"). But the aside is closer to the end of the sentence, so you stumble over it more.

I tried this:

> You let them -- even encouraged them TO -- consume your content, and in return they sent you traffic.

But that didn't seem right either.

Comment: I don't see a problem. "Let" and "encouraged" are  preterites, and "consume" is infinitival i.e. untensed.

Comment: It reads better to me without repetition of the first instance of the object *(**them**)*. Not that unscripted interjections have clearly-defined syntax anyway, but we normally apply the relevant syntax of *the most recent element.* Note that the whole reason for the speaker "interrupting" himself here is to juxtapose ***let*** and ***encourage***, so it's better to put them closer together with no intervening repeated object before the emphatic second verb: *You let -- even **encouraged** -- them to consume your content...*

Comment: ... And if I couldn't make bigger adjustments, I'd go with << You let them – you even encouraged them to – consume your content, and in return they sent you traffic. >> It still sounds clunky. But surely the best solution here is << You allowed them – even encouraged them – to consume your content, and in return they sent you traffic. >> I'd agree that  << You let them – even encouraged them – consume your content ... >> is ungrammatical. The aside needs to correspond to 'you let them' in how it catenates.

Comment: One often hears talking heads on American TV say things like "We have and will continue to make progress on that issue". I see this question as related to that, although with a less egregious example.

Comment: What you should do is to make a decision (is it *let* or *encouraged*?) and rewrite! Such constructions have a place in representing someone changing their mind or thinking as they speak (in which case poor grammar is excusable), but you shouldn't deliberately use them in formal prose.

Comment: To summarize other comments: When a sentence and its aside require different structures, **fix the conflict**.

Comment: The last version is probably the most correct, but I think the original version with the mismatch would usually be considered acceptable. People are flexible about this kind of thing.

Comment: Change *let* to *allow*: *You allowed them — even encouraged them — to consume your content...* Or: *You allowed — even encouraged — them to consume your content...* If you want to keep *let*, you can go full-on literary with *bade*: *You let them -- even bade them -- consume your content...*

Comment: If the supplement is to the whole clause, move it to the end:  "You let them consume your content, even encouraged them."  Splitting the clause makes it awkward.  If the supplement is to the verb fragment, you need the "to":  "You let them, even encouraged them to, consume your content."

Comment: The natural pause is after the to, so that's where it should go. This is speech, not writing.

Comment: @Deane Your last example seems OK to me. The verb "let" takes a bare infinitival clause, so the main clause _You let them consume your content, and in return they sent you traffic_, is fine. In the supplement, there is ellipsis of the VP “consume your content, …”, resulting in stranding of _to_. This reduced supplement clause is understood as _even encouraged them to consume your content …_,